# Find all the functions f: $\mathbb R^{2}\to \mathbb R$, where $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}=0$

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus

I am not sure if my way of thinking is convincing enough.
$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=0$ if and only if $g = C$, where $C = h(y)$.
It means that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = h(y)$, which is a differentiable function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrate in $y$ to find 
$$
\frac{\partial{f}}{{\partial x}}=g(x)
$$
for some function of $x$ alone. Now integrate in $x$ to find 
$$
f(x,y)=\int_{x_0}^xg(t)\mathrm dt+H(y)
$$
By the same principal. Setting $G(x)=\int_{x_0}^xg(t)\mathrm dt$ makes things cleaner, and 
$$
f(x,y)=G(x)+H(y)
$$
Check to see that your conditions are indeed satisfied.